# aws glue get-databases returns empty list on CLI

Tags: aws-cli, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have two databases on my Glue Catalog, however when I run the command

$ aws glue get-databases

```
{
    "DatabaseList": []
}
```

I get an empty list. How can I make it return the ones that exist?

Answer (score 1):

Another fix for this is to use `--region` for example
`aws glue get-databases --region us-east-1`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my aws cli was configured on a different region than the one I was working on.

To change it I just edited ~/.aws/config to the correct one.